# CSS/webkit/animation keep from re-sizing entire div

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79c07jy7/) as an example.  I am using [this](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) code for the animation.

Right now, the animation is making the content below bounce up and down as it animates.  How can I stop this? I have always been pretty terrible at html/css margins and positioning, and this one is just confusing me to no end.

```css
.loader,

.loader:before,

.loader:after {

  background: #0dc5c1;

  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;

  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;

  width: 1em;

  height: 4em;

}

.loader:before,

.loader:after {

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  content: '';

}

.loader:before {

  left: -1.5em;

  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;

  animation-delay: -0.32s;

}

.loader {

  text-indent: -9999em;

  margin: 15px;

  position: relative;

  font-size: 6px;

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);

  transform: translateZ(0);

  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;

  animation-delay: -0.16s;

}

.loader:after {

  left: 1.5em;

}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 0 #0dc5c1;

    height: 4em;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 -2em #0dc5c1;

    height: 5em;

  }

}

@keyframes load1 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 0 #0dc5c1;

    height: 4em;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 -2em #0dc5c1;

    height: 5em;

  }

}
```

```html
<ul class='my_list'>
  <li>Item 1</li>

  <div class='loader'></div>

  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Adding more info for clarity.
I am trying to add a loading placeholder on a nested UL in cases where it is empty.  My HTML will end up looking more like this:

```css
.loader,

.loader:before,

.loader:after {

  background: #0dc5c1;

  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;

  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;

  width: 1em;

  height: 4em;

}

.loader:before,

.loader:after {

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  content: '';

}

.loader:before {

  left: -1.5em;

  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;

  animation-delay: -0.32s;

}

.loader {

  text-indent: -9999em;

  margin: 15px;

  position: relative;

  font-size: 6px;

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);

  transform: translateZ(0);

  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;

  animation-delay: -0.16s;

}

.loader:after {

  left: 1.5em;

}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 0 #0dc5c1;

    height: 4em;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 -2em #0dc5c1;

    height: 5em;

  }

}

@keyframes load1 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 0 #0dc5c1;

    height: 4em;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 -2em #0dc5c1;

    height: 5em;

  }

}
```

```html
<ul class='items'>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul class='results'>
      <li>Result 1</li>
      <li>Result 2</li>
      <li>Result 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li class='loader'></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Still waiting for results -->
    <!-- Spinner here -->
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul class='results'>
      <li>Result 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the layout using position absolute on the transforming div, and position relative on the list. The transforming div can be removed from the list, and then positioned using top/right/left/bottom. [Link to an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/1a8f3mxf/)

Changed HTML:

```
<ul class='my_list'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class='loader'></div>
```

Added CSS:

```
.loader {
  top: 35px;
  left: 40px;
}
.my_list li {
  padding-bottom:50px;
}

.my_list {
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I updated my post to give a bit more info on what I'm trying to do.  I don't think a div outside with a relative position will work for me, since both of my ul's will be generated on the fly. EDIT: Updated again.